Cyrillic bindings to function keys doesn't work in Chrome. xkb
I have binding Cyrrilic character to function keys it it works everywhere except Google Chrome. Different bindings to fn keys ( Return, Tab, any english character, Unicode symbols ect) work as expected.
key  { [ Cyrillic_sha, Cyrillic_SHA ] }; // work as regular f11
key  { [ Cyrillic_shcha, Cyrillic_SHCHA ] }; // work as regular f12
key  { [ Return ] }; // Work as expect
key  { [ U2026 ] }; //  … work as expect
